# Is there anything wrong with wrapping a top-down class in a static method

Tags: c#, class, static, io, tdd

I know how to program, but i want to become a better programmer. I have certain classes that are more IO oriented. One takes in a url with a macro, some page numbers, and an downloader interface, an some xpath to combine many htmls into one managable xml.

The problem comes in my mind is, do i let the end user access the methods that do the work, or do i make the class have one single "run" method? Or do i leave the class as is, with no run method, and add a method to a utility class that simply constructs the object and returns its ultimate value.

making a class with a single public method feels wrong, but on the other hand, making a bunch of public methods that could be relied on, and therefore kill my ability to re-factor also feels wrong.

Comment: please add your language to the question tags. thanks

Comment: Done, sorry about that

Comment: If you worry about your ability to refactor, build the class against an interface. Decide what the user should be able to do / see and design the interface accordingly, then approach the class design to comply with the interface.

Comment: Thats fine but my unease is that I feel my end user should see one thing. I cant say ive ever seen intelesense on a class have one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here seems to be the [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), your method seems to be doing (too) many different things and thus would require many public methods to be testable. This is a common pointer that a class is "wrongly" built when writing unit-tests.

What I would recommend here is to split your class into multiple ones, each containing part of the logic and one responsibility only. In each of those classes, the main method is public and does the intended job while being testable. The original class now has the job to use the output of those other objects without "knowing" how they are doing it.

Comment: Well in a sense i already have that. I use the htmlagilitypack, and a downloading wrapper. I also use the agility pack to execute xpath.

Dont get me wrong im open to discussion along those lines, but my class has 2 methods each about 10 lines

Comment: Let's reverse the problem. Let's say that both methods are public. Do they make sense from a user point of view? If so, it's perfectly OK to leave them public. If not, one of them is an internal function that should be private or performs some logic that could/should be performed by another object. In a sense, having a bunch of methods in one class hinders your ability to refactor, but spreading the responsibilities to dedicated object increases it.

Comment: hrm, well from a user point of a view i would probably think "Why do i have to call the first method, just to feed its result into the second method" At least from the standpoint of its intended use. I suppose they could use the methods separately for a different purpose but im not making it for that purpose.